# disable options in dynamically created selectboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im dynamically creating new dropdown lists for the user in order to input something in a database. I need to disable the previous selections of the user in all the dropdown lists that he creates, (For example, if in the 1st dpl chooses the 1st option then he won't be able to choose it in other dpls.)
Code is -----> [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/replay94_/vx5hvbx6/1/)!
The code works fine on my pc, I don't know why it doesn't in jsfiddle but you will get an idea of what the code does! I also noticed that it only runs the js when the 1st select box is changing state and not when the other ones do.

I tried these but no luck... any tips? (also there is an extra thing i tried in the fiddle, it was to long to post it here)

```
$('select').on('change', function() {

    /* enable any previously disabled options */
    $('option[disabled]').prop('disabled', false);

    /* loop over each select */
    $('select').each(function() {

       /* for every other select, disable option which matches this this.value */
       $('select').not(this).find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').prop('disabled', true); 

    });

});
```

**EDIT:**

> The values from the dropdown lists are from a database, in the example
>   I change it so it can be easier

Comment: `this.value` is probably causing you problems. `this` changes context inside your `.each()` loop. I suggest making a variable before your each loop, `var thisVal = this.value` and then using `thisVal` inside the `each`. Good luck.

Comment: no that doesn't work!

Comment: Yes, you may have *more* problems than that, but I'm almost certain that that is one of the problems.

Comment: maybe is the way i am creating the extra select boxes?

Comment: The first step would be to fix your fiddle (missing braces and undefined vars), so that we can try and help.

Comment: Have a look at this one: https://jsfiddle.net/npmb1ehf/9/

Comment: @TKoL that ain't working with my problem! the select boxes can be countless

Comment: Your jsfiddle is not doing a good job of showing what the problem is. I don't even understand how to use it. Can you make a simplified one similar to the one I provided?

Comment: I have a section that contains some fields for inputting data in a database. the user when it clicks on the add button can create more fields. I need the field that contains the services(1st field which takes the options from the database) to disable the options previously selected by the user

Comment: @TKoL i updates the fiddle so now its more simple

Comment: Your expected behavior is still unclear. Do you only want disabling to work forwards? Eg select 1 disables future select options, and select 2 disables future select options but not select 1? Do you want the disabling to be additive, eg if select 1 has 'a' selected and selected 2 has 'b' selected, select 3 should have 'a' and 'b' disabled?

Comment: it should be additive no more than 1 selection in general!